KNNImputer (Python) - problem with the 'nan'
I have a problem when I use KNNImputer to replace the missing values ​​NaN of a categorical variable. The other variables besides nutrition_score_fr have no NaN. Only nutrition_scrore_fr contains 8% missing values.
When I pass this code, the nan are not replaced. I just get the string nan instead of the values ​​a, b, c, d, or e of the variable nutrition_score_fr.
Why doesn't KNNImputer replace the NaN?
Here is the code:
# Convertir les catégories en entiers
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
df['nutrition_grade_fr_encoded'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(df['nutrition_grade_fr'].astype(str))

# Inclure toutes les colonnes dans l'imputation, y compris les colonnes numériques et  'nutrition_grade_fr_encoded'
columns_to_impute = ['energy_100g', 'proteins_100g', 'fat_100g', 'carbohydrates_100g', 'salt_100g', 'sugars_100g', 'saturated-fat_100g', 'nutrition_grade_fr_encoded']

# Imputation avec KNN
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)

# Imputation des valeurs manquantes en utilisant toutes les colonnes spécifiées
df_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(df[columns_to_impute])

# Convertir le résultat en DataFrame avec les mêmes colonnes
df_imputed = pd.DataFrame(df_imputed, columns=columns_to_impute).reset_index(drop=True)

# Reconversion de 'nutrition_grade_fr_encoded' en catégories
df_imputed['nutrition_grade_fr'] =    label_encoder.inverse_transform(df_imputed['nutrition_grade_fr_encoded'].round().astype(int))

# 3. Réintégrer les colonnes imputées dans le DataFrame original
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df['nutrition_grade_fr'] = df_imputed['nutrition_grade_fr']

I just get the string nan instead of the values ​​a, b, c, d, or e of the variable nutrition_score_fr.
